# List<T> thread safety

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions

I am using the below code

```
var processed = new List<Guid>();
Parallel.ForEach(items, item => 
{
    processed.Add(SomeProcessingFunc(item));
});
```

Is the above code thread safe? Is there a chance of processed list getting corrupted? Or should i use a lock before adding?

```
var processed = new List<Guid>();
Parallel.ForEach(items, item => 
{
    lock(items.SyncRoot)
        processed.Add(SomeProcessingFunc(item));
});
```

thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779165/parallel-foreach-loop-odd-behavior.

Comment: @Martinho: Yes. I read that List<T> is not thread safe. But I am unable to understand that even if multiple threads are adding to the list how can that corrupt the list.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: an example: the list keeps track of how many elements it has. When you add one, it places it in the next position, and increment the count. Well, there's a race condition right there: two threads could both add an element, and count increase only by one (and one element getting lost in the process).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread-safe List<T> property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874317/thread-safe-listt-property)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No! It is not safe at all, because `processed.Add` is not. You can do following:

```
items.AsParallel().Select(item => SomeProcessingFunc(item)).ToList();
```

Keep in mind that `Parallel.ForEach` was created mostly for *imperative* operations for each element of sequence. What you do is map: project each value of sequence. That is what `Select` was created for. `AsParallel` scales it across threads in most efficient manner.

This code works correctly:

```
var processed = new List<Guid>();
Parallel.ForEach(items, item => 
{
    lock(items.SyncRoot)
        processed.Add(SomeProcessingFunc(item));
});
```

but makes no sense in terms of multithreading. `lock`ing at each iteration forces totally sequential execution, bunch of threads will be waiting for single thread.

Comment: to be complete why: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx near the end it has an topic on Thread Safety

Comment: @rene: tack `#c9721fa0-1cd9-4a21-818c-98d164c9fc14` to the end of that address and it points directly to the relevant section ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would it be better to use ConcurrentBag<T> as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779165/parallel-foreach-loop-odd-behavior

Comment: Can you pls. provide your inputs as to whether AsParallel would be better than using ConcurrentBag<T> ?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser yes, when you really need concurrent access to data structure you should use `ConcurrentBag<T>`. but in reality with such high level library as PLINQ it is rarely needed.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
var processed = new ConcurrentBag<Guid>();
```

See [parallel foreach loop - odd behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779165/parallel-foreach-loop-odd-behavior).

Comment: The `ConcurrentQueue<T>` [is preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400133/when-to-use-blockingcollection-and-when-concurrentbag-instead-of-listt/64823123#64823123) to the `ConcurrentBag<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

From Jon Skeet's Book [C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471):

> As part of Parallel Extensions in .Net 4, there are several new collections in a new `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace. These are designed to be safe in the face of concurrent operations from multiple threads, with relatively little locking.

These include:

- `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`
- `BlockingCollection<T>`
- `ConcurrentBag<T>`
- `ConcurrentQueue<T>`
- `ConcurrentStack<T>`
- `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`
- and others

Comment: Agreed.  See my answer, which uses a type from the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020524/976896) of Andrey:

```
items.AsParallel().Select(item => SomeProcessingFunc(item)).ToList();
```

You could also write

```
items.AsParallel().ForAll(item => SomeProcessingFunc(item));
```

This makes the query that is behind it even more efficient because no merge is required, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383744.aspx).
Make sure the `SomeProcessingFunc` function is thread-safe.
And I think, but didn't test it, that you still need a lock if the list can be modified in an other thread (adding or removing) elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Using ConcurrentBag of type Something**

```
var bag = new ConcurrentBag<List<Something>>;
var items = GetAllItemsINeed();
Parallel.For(items,i =>                          
   {
      bag.Add(i.DoSomethingInEachI());
   });
```

Comment: should be `var bag = new ConcurrentBag<Something>();`

Answer (score 0):

reading is thread safe, but adding is not. You need a reader/writer lock setup as adding may cause the internal array to resize which would mess up a concurrent read.

If you can guarantee the array won't resize on add, you may be safe to add while reading, but don't quote me on that.

But really, a list is just an interface to an array.