# Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, exception, iterator

I've been getting this exception out in the field. I don't understand how the collection can be modified while iterating. I copy everything to local variables at the start of the method.

```
  public void Flush() {
            var tempEntities = attachedEntities.Select(item => item).ToList();
            attachedEntities.Clear();

            var tempEntitiesToDelete = entitiesToDelete.Select(item => item).ToList();
            entitiesToDelete.Clear();

            foreach (var attachedEntity in tempEntities) {
                var isTransient = (bool)GetPrivateField(attachedEntity.GetType(), attachedEntity, "isTransient");
                if (isTransient)
                    db.Insert(attachedEntity);
                else
                    db.Update(attachedEntity);
            }

            foreach (var entity in tempEntitiesToDelete)
                db.Delete(entity);
        }
```

Stack Trace

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1 Enumerator[Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.IEntity].VerifyState () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1 Enumerator[Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.IEntity].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable <CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator1D`2[Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.IEntity,Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.IEntity].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.IEntity].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.IEntity]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.Session.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.Session.Commit () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Compass.Mobile.Core.Bootstrap.CommandBus.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: `.Select(item => item)` is a nop, by the way. It won't do anything useful.

Comment: Usually this is a threading problem.  Some other thread modifying either the attachedEntities or entitiesToDelete objects while ToList() is iterating them.

Comment: @Chris, try removing it. I think it's worse than a nop in this case.

Comment: Since you are `ToList`ing the enumerable, there's actually no need to `foreach` - you can use a basic `for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)` construct...but as to why you're getting the exception, I'd be guessing, but I'd say your `db` methods somehow alter the passed-in `entity` object enough to trigger an enumerable changed? Edit: no, that doesn't make sense...I think I'm with @HansPassant - something else is poking around in your data - another thread?

Comment: AHH. I didn't even think about the ToList(). I was looking at the loop...but the stacktrace clearly shows the exception happening on "ToList()"

Comment: How did you generate attachedEntities, which is not in view here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the stack trace, it's not failing inside your `foreach` (or enumerating `tempEntities` which is a plain list) but inside one of `ToList` calls, when `Select` iterator's underlying list checks its state before moving on to next item.

This line in your stack trace makes me believe so:

```
at System.Linq.Enumerable <CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator1D`2[Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.IEntity,Compass.Mobile.Core.DataAccess.IEntity].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Your foreach loop variable is just a list, so it doesn't go through `Select`. This leads me to believe that either `attachedEntities` or `entitiesToDelete` change while you're doing `Select` over them:

```
/* Failing here... */
var tempEntities = attachedEntities.Select(item => item).ToList();
attachedEntities.Clear();

/* ...or here*/
var tempEntitiesToDelete = entitiesToDelete.Select(item => item).ToList();
entitiesToDelete.Clear();

/* ...but not here! */
foreach (var attachedEntity in tempEntities) {
   // ...
}
```

It could very well be a concurrency issue.

By the way, you really don't need `Select (item => item)`, it would just be an identity projection.

Comment: Yes. I just realized this as well. So whats the best way to take a "Snapshot" of the lists and process those entities. There are other threads accessing this.

Comment: @ChrisKooken create a new list, then lock/otherwise synchronize access, iterate over the original, inserting your "to do" items into the new list. Then process the new list(s).

Comment: You shouldn't have threads accessing shared lists **at all**. This is really dangerous because [lists are not thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020486/listt-thread-safety). If it's too hard to change current design, consider placing `lock`s around the code accessing them (but beware of deadlocks), or, better, use types from `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

Comment: If i were to use a ConcurrentBag, do i need any locks anywhere?

Comment: @Chris: If you only access these two lists from other threads, using `ConcurrentBag`s instead of `List`s should make your code thread-safe. [Take a look at this article](http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-system_collections_concurrent_concurrentbag). If you're accessing  shared instances of other classes from different threads, you'll need locks if some of these classes aren't thread safe. You can check thread safety of any .NET class in MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
foreach (var entity in tempEntitiesToDelete)
     db.Delete(entity);
```

With:

```
for (var i = tempEntitiesToDelete.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   db.Delete(tempEntitiesToDelete[i]);
```

I had this problem when I tried to delete while looping through; it was trying to modify the list of items.  Therefore, looping backward fixed it for me.

Comment: adding .ToList() or .ToArray() to the tempEntitiesToDelete in the foreach would work too.

Comment: If exception happened while enumerating `tempEntities`, there wouldn't be `System.Linq.Enumerable <CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator1D``2` in the stack trace, would there? It's hard to say without the line numbers of course.