# Does For loop check linq expression at each iteration

Tags: c#, .net

Having the following for loop:

```
        for (var i = list.Count - 1; i >= list.OrderBy(x => x).First(); i--)
            if (list.Contains(i))
                list.RemoveAt(i);
```

1. Does **list.Count()** get checked every iteration?
2. Does **list.OrderBy(x => x.Key).First()** get executed every iteration
3. Should this be thread safe? because of adding/removing?

What I'm driving at is that, during the for loop execution items may be added to the list (elsewhere-in a different method)

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and see *exactly* what gets called and when.  (That said, you don't call `list.Count()` anywhere in the snippet you've shown, so it doesn't get called *at all*.)

Comment: the first part of a `for` loop is executed once the other two parts are executed once per iteration.

Comment: yes the orderby will get executed.

Comment: @Servy, the first part of the `for` loop is `var i = list.Count() - 1`.

Comment: @juharr Look at the revision history.  They edited the code after I commented.

Comment: @HimBromBeere True, fixed.

Comment: please take the time to create some actually working example. List does not have a method ContainsKey(). Perhaps you are thinking of Dictionary, but Dictionary does not have a method RemoveAt()

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Remove every time except the one with the highest value of `Key`? And as for is it thread safe, probably not. If items are removed, you can't guarantee that `i` is within bounds anymore.

Comment: I see you attempted to fix the errors in your code I pointed out, but it seems to still contain further errors. Please try to compile this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: No because it is only the starting value. This part will be visited only once at the start of the loop

2: Yes because the linq expression has to be evaluated to get the result value. If you want to avoid it execute the linq expression once before the loop and save it into a separate value:

```
int end = list.OrderBy(x => x.Key).First(); 
for (var i = list.Count() - 1; i >= end; i--) 
    if (list.ContainsKey(i))
        list.RemoveAt(i)
```

EDIT:

If your list might change dynamically, then of course the way you use it now would be a preferable solution, since you could accommodate to the changes.

as for question 3: [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020524/5174469) says that the `Add` method is **not** thread safe

Comment: That's the thing, list may be removed from/added to elsewhere DURING the for iteration. That's the reason I do not wish to save it in the variable

Comment: @BobSwanson then you could accommodate to the changes online, the way you are using it now. Is `list` a `Dictionary` ?

Comment: @BobSwanson: You aren't going to make this thread safe without some kind of locking.